# Imacros won't click button?

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to build a script to post auto blog on Google Sites but the problem is that the button won't click. This is my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mxq.png

Code Button

```
<div aria-label="New page" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" id="create-new-btn" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-collapse-left" aria-disabled="false"><span id="sites-collaborator-bar-create-new-page-icon" class="sites-camelot-icon"></span></div>
```

This is my code in Imacros

Code IMACROS

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/testing/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:create-new-btn
```

This is other code but in Javascript Imacros

Code JAVA

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES" + "\n";
macro += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT 500" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/testing/" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:create-new-btn" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: you need javascript command for this button, regular imacros won't work

Answer (score 2):

you can simply load create new page form instead of clicking on the button, since to click you'll have to emulate mouse hovering and use javascript.
Just load: https://sites.google.com/site/your-site/system/app/pages/createPage?source=/home

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around is to use the `CLICK` command in imacros like so:

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/testing/
CLICK X=1000 Y=10
```

where **X** is the distance from the top-left side of the browser to the middle of the button you want to click, and **Y** is the distance from the top of the browser to the middle of the button you want to click. You are able to measure these distances by doing a **print-screen** and going into a tool like **paint** and measuring the pixel distances (or any other tool you find more convenient).

Answer (score 0):

You can try imacros for Firefox instead of Chrome, because in terms of clicking buttons imacros somehow perform better in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try clicking on the span inside that div. Perhaps this trigger the action.

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/testing/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:sites-collaborator-bar-create-new-page-icon
```